# Extending a section of a finite morphism to a normal variety from an open

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a finite surjective morphism of algebraic varieties with $Y$ normal, and let $U$ be open in $Y$. Assume we have a section of $f$ over $U$, i.e. a morphism $s:U\to X$ such that $f\circ s=id_U$. I want to show that $s$ extends uniquely to a section over the whole of $Y$.

I think this reduces to the affine case, and we also can assume that $U$ is a distinguished open set. So let $Y=Spec\ A,\ X=Spec\ B,$ $B$ finite over $A$, $A$ integrally closed. Then we have a diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
B_t @<<< B\\
@Af_tAA @AfAA\\
A_t @<<< A
\end{CD}

and a section $s$ of $f_t$, which we have to extend to a section of $f$.

I guess that if we have $s:B_t\to A_t$, the assumptions will imply that the image of $B$ naturally mapped into $B_t$ under $s$ will lie in $A$. However, I was unable to prove that.

Comment: One way to do this is to appeal to Zariski's main theorem. One version says, if you have a finite morphism $g:Z\to Y$ with $Y$ normal, all irreducible and $g$ birational, then $g$ is an isomorphism. Apply to $Z$, the closure of $s(U)$.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to write it up tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\xi$ be the generic point of $X$ and $\eta$ be the generic point of $Y$.
Since $f$ is finite and dominant, we have $f^{-1}(\eta)=\{\xi\}$, so $s(\eta)=\xi$.
The composition $k(\eta)\xrightarrow{s^*}k(\xi)\xrightarrow{f^*}k(\eta)$ is the identity, so $f$ is birational.

Consider an affine open subset $V\simeq \operatorname{Spec} A$ of $Y$.
Set $U=f^{-1}(V)\simeq \operatorname{Spec} B$.
Since $f$ is birational, we have inclusions $A\subset B\subset \operatorname{Frac}(A)$.
Since $B$ is finite over $A$ and $A$ is normal, we get $A=B$.
Therefore $f$ is must be an isomorphism.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I had in mind, missed that $X$ is irreducible so didn't manage to identify Frac$(B)$ with Frac$(A)$. It's nice to have an elementary proof, thanks!